# Error "stack level too deep" when compiling sass with nested SUSY calls

Tags: jruby, susy-compass

I have found in a particular .scss file I'm working with that whenever I call `@include span(...)` inside of `@include with-layout(...)`, like such

```
@include with-layout(10 0 split){
    div.header{
        @include span(8 of 10);
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
error myFile.scss (org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2339:in `collect': stack level too deep)
```

This leads me to believe there is some sort of infinite recursion occurring with these particular nested properties.  Does anyone know how this should be fixed, or what the proper way to nest these `@include` statements is?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it happens any time you nest those? I can't recreate your problem with the code listed. Even a [more deeply nested example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/3aa06f85e62e73b9b7c0) works on Sassmeister.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your mixin definitions? 
My guess is that your span mixin contains a @content directive, causing an infinite loop:

Your code applies the `div.header {}` content block to all @content directives located in the with-layout mixin, but if each `div.header {}` block contains a @content directive via the span mixin, SASS will keep replacing each @content directive with a div.header containing a @content directive, etc. etc.

This could be fixed by removing the @content directive from your span mixin, or defining a new span mixin that doesn't contain a @content directive.

Comment: with-layout and span are simply mixins that are part of SUSY.  You can find documentation on them here:
http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Oh I missed that, my mistake. See line 29-34 in the span definition for the @content directive that I think is the culprit: https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/88c58978f8ff9334577e3a002f46a425b01a16c7/sass/susy/language/susy/_span.scss

Comment: Not sure exactly how to fix, but I would look into nested context: http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toolkit/#nested-context